# T-SQL: User defined column cannot be converted to int for ordering

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table:

```
id  delivered
1   carrot
1   potato
1   potato
2   potato
3   carrot
3   carrot
3   potato
```

Desired output:

```
id  carrots     potatoes
3   2           1
1   1           2
2   0           1
```

I want to see the customers who ordered both at top.

I'm able to do the group by but when I try to order results, I receive this error:

`Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'carrots' to data type int.`

How would you do it?

Code on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/aa69a/5) and here:

```
SELECT 
id,
SUM(CASE WHEN delivered = 'carrot' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'carrots',
SUM(CASE WHEN delivered = 'potato' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'potatoes'
FROM schedule
GROUP BY id
--ORDER BY carrots DESC, potatoes DESC  [This sort of works but not all the time. Prefer code after]
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN 'carrots' > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + (CASE WHEN 'potatoes' > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

T-SQL/Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2016.

Comment: `'carrots'` is a literal string. `'` are for quoting string, not object names. Either drop the single quotes, or use brackets (`[]`).

Comment: Thanks. Still fails when I drop the single quotes. Sqlfiddle gives back the reason for failure 'invalid column name', my actual query gives back 'varchar conversion'.

Comment: Please do not edit question in place, because you are invalidating existing answer/comments.

Answer (score 1):

Identifiers are quoted with `"` or `[]` or do not qoute them at all:

```
SELECT 
id,
SUM(CASE WHEN delivered = 'carrot' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS carrots,
SUM(CASE WHEN delivered = 'potato' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS potatoes
FROM schedule
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY carrots, potatoes;
```

---

EDIT:

```
SELECT 
  id,
  SUM(CASE WHEN delivered = 'carrot' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS carrots,
  SUM(CASE WHEN delivered = 'potato' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS potatoes
FROM schedule
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY SUM(CASE WHEN delivered = 'carrot' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + 
         SUM(CASE WHEN delivered = 'potato' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END);
```

or cte:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT 
  id,
  SUM(CASE WHEN delivered = 'carrot' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS carrots,
  SUM(CASE WHEN delivered = 'potato' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS potatoes
FROM schedule
GROUP BY id
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN carrots > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + (CASE WHEN potatoes > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=593ae7ae3775faaff96cf9f6ddf4a5c0)**

Comment: Thanks. Still fails when I drop the '. Sqlfiddle gives the reason for failure as invalid column name, my actual query in SMSS gives back the varchar reason.

Comment: @ChristinaZhou Sure I provided alternatives

Answer (score 1):

Use this logic:

```
ORDER BY (MAX(CASE WHEN carrots > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + 
          MAX(CASE WHEN potatoes > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
         ) DESC
```

Although SQL Server accepts column aliases in the `ORDER BY`, it is not so keen their use in expressions.  Note how they fail [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6d597a97640523f737fa7811a9f81bf1).